# BigQuery: Import of Cloud Firestore export treats map fields as bytes

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-bigquery

I have a Firestore collection that I've been [importing into BigQuery tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-firestore) via the [managed import/export service](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import). Recently, schema auto-detection has begun failing for these imports, resulting in Firestore map fields being treated as unqueryable `byte` fields in the BigQuery table.

The docs mention that this may happen if unique field names in your Firestore collection [exceeds BigQuery's 10,000 column per table limit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import#column_limit). This collection definitely exceeds that limit, however, I was under the impression that using the `--projection_fields` allowlist param would limit the amount of columns BigQuery tried to ingest. Is this not the case? Will an import operation fail schema detection regardless of `--projection_fields` if the collection exceeds 10,000 unique names at all, or am I missing something?

For reference, here's an example of the CLI command I'm using to load the import:

```
bq load --source_format=DATASTORE_BACKUP --replace \
  --projection_fields=id,user, <...etc> \
  dataset.table \
  gs://backups/<backup_file>
```

Comment: I have the same issue with a collection containing a record field. Instead array I am using record type because I need query by ID which it is impossible if the field were an array querying by index. Now I have bad news that each key is a column on loading into BigQuery. Now change the database structure is painful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello I'm facing the same problem here:
[map as byte](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tvpab.png)

But I couldn't find the right codec to decode the map from the byte.
The solution seems to be using sub-collection instead of maps fields in your Firestore documents.

You can still try my solution if you can't change the structure of your Firestore documents:
an ETL job to create the raw tables before loading them into BigQuery instead of using the managed import/export service.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping to avoid having to create a one-off ETL, but it seems that the Firestore import won't work on a collection with this many fields, regardless of how many columns would actually be ingested via `--projection_fields`, so that must be the only option.

Comment: Google uses protobuf so you need decode base64 and decode proto too. There are tools to handle it like https://github.com/sj14/multicode

Comment: I tried using this but I don't get actually how it is encoded by google. What I understand in your message is decoding base64 first to obtain the proto, then decoding the proto. 

It looks like decoding base 64 doesn't give me anything that I could decode again...

Comment: It looks like I'm going to have to go the ETL route. Has anyone tried this? Any suggestions? There is some information about ETL in Google Cloud [here](https://cloud.google.com/learn/what-is-etl), but not sure which services to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can try decoding those bytes from Base64.

Sometimes it produces some gibberish characters, but there are cases where it can work.